# Navegacion entre Forms y el uso de RAM

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, windows-forms

Intentare ser lo mas explicito posible.

Actualmente para navegar entre forms uso

```
Me.Close()
Form1.show()
```

Estoy seguro que llevar a cabo esta practica con programas grandes esta mal porque cuando navego de un form a otro el grafico de `Procces memory (MB)`  crece exponencialmente quiza este leyendo mal el grafico pero aunque cierre forms `Me.close` este sube y sube. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En un principio esto me parecia correcto pero... Estoy en lo cierto?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

que formas usan ustedes para navegar en una aplicación?

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: si sube y sube, es porque en algun lado estas dejando cosas en memoria y no las estas sacando. Porque haces me.close()? si haces algo despues de ese close, entonces no se esta cerrando. Estas haciendo bien el dispose del mismo?

Comment: A todos los forms menos al principal les doy me.close, pero uso mucho consultas a una base de datos donde despues de cerrar la conexion no hago uso del dispose como bien me indicas. De seguro ese sea el problema general.